# how to implement a two way binding between components that are not parent and child in Vue 3 js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, two-way-binding, vue-reactivity

I'm using [this](https://sampleapis.com/api-list/coffee) free coffee API to fetch data.

Each coffee drink item is populated in a Vue Card component. The Card component has a `counter: 0` that the user can `increment()` and `decrement()`.

**Card.vue**

```js
import {store} from '../store'
import {ref} from 'vue'
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            store,
            count: ref(0)
        }
    },
    props: ['drink'],
    methods: {
        decrement(){
            (this.count != 0) ? this.count-- : this.count = 0
            store.decrement(this.drink.title,this.drink.id,this.count)
        },
        increment(){
            this.count++
            store.increment(this.drink.title,this.drink.id,this.count)
        }
    },
}
```

I'm using the [Reactivity API](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api) for state management.

**Store.js**(state management)

```js
import { reactive, ref } from 'vue'

export const store = reactive({
    drinks : ref([]),

    increment(drinkName,id,count) {
        let drink = this.drinks.find(drink => drink.drinkID === id);

        if(drink) {
            drink.drinkCount = count
        } else {
            this.drinks.push({
                drinkID : id,
                drinkName : drinkName,
                drinkCount : count,
            })
        }
    },
    decrement(drinkName,id,count) {
        let drink = this.drinks.find(drink => drink.drinkID === id);
        if(drink) {
            drink.drinkCount = count
            if(drink.drinkCount == 0) this.drinks.splice(this.drinks.indexOf(drink),1);
        }
    },
    remove(id) {
        let drink = this.drinks.find(drink => drink.drinkID === id);
        if(drink) {
            drink.drinkCount = 0
            if(drink.drinkCount == 0) this.drinks.splice(this.drinks.indexOf(drink),1);
        }
    }
})
```

Finally, I have a Sidebar(shopping cart) component that uses the Reactivity API to reactively add coffee drinks to the cart based on the Changes on the Card component.

I implemented a remove button for the sidebar such that the `remove()` function will reset the count to zero and remove it from the cart. You can see the code in the Store.js section. The issue I am having is that everything is updated in the shopping cart and the item is removed as expected but nothing happens in the `Card Component`. The `counter` in the Card Component does not update.

note: that the `Card Component` and `Sidebar Compnent` do not have a parent and child relationship.

Here is a link for the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-bartik-rjxsx3)

Comment: That would be easier to debug and help if you tried to make a reproduction codesandbox :/

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, here is a link for the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-bartik-rjxsx3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

each coffee has to possess its own `count` field. but you have `count` for each `Card Component`. also you're re-assigning `HotView` and `IcedView` components' state with fetching data in `mounted()` hook

I get it work [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-shaw-0wcscf?file=/src/App.vue)